# Google Maps API v3 -- How to convert .getBounds() to to pixel coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I know how to use an overlay projection to get a LatLng object, and then convert that single LatLng to pixels, using .fromLatLngToDivPixel()

However, .getBounds() returns a pair of LatLng coordinates. I've tried accessing it like it's an array (as in specifying index[1] for example) but that does not work. It doesn't seem to be an array.

Is there a way to convert the value from .getBounds() to pixel data?

Comment: And you didn't found informations about what getBounds() returns and how to access the properties?

Comment: Refrain from being a smartass when talking to me.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds

Did you find that information?

Comment: of course, I can't imagine how anyone couldn't find it

Comment: It's so much more polite and reputable of you to point it out to me, considering that you can tell that I am unable to find it, rather than passive aggressively call me an idiot and not assist me in finding it at all.

Comment: What do you expect, should I repeat the documentation here for you? As you can see LatLngBounds have 4 methods that return LatLng's , there isn't "the value"

Comment: Why would I expect anything other than for you to assist me by pointing out to me exactly where in the documentation it lists what I'm looking for, seeing as I have been unable to find it? You've been incredibly rude.

Comment: You still didn't say what you are looking for, because I told you that there isn't "the value" for a LatLngBounds-object. I'm also not sure what's rude in my comments, but you only have to read your own comments to see what's rude in yours.

Comment: I was not asking for "the value" of a LatLngBounds object. If you had read my question with any sort of care, you would notice I was referring to the value that is returned from .getBounds().

Your attitude towards answering my question straightly from the beginning is what is rude. Don't even try and flip the script. You know exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: the getBounds()-method returns a LatLngBounds-object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However, .getBounds() returns a pair of LatLng coordinates. I've tried
> accessing it like it's an array (as in specifying index[1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) for
> example) but that does not work. It doesn't seem to be an array.

LatLngBounds **is not an array**, it's an object and [**the documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) shows you two methods to get the coordinates:

```
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

Those two methods return LatLng objects which you can pass to `fromLatLngToDivPixel()`
However, if you got your LatLngBounds object by reading `map.getBounds()` then you already know what the pixel values should be, (the corners of your map container DIV).